# R: Synchronising data from multiple sources to 1 row per day

Tags: r, date, dataframe, merge, synchronization

I have collected data from different sources, which means the data collected isn't syncronised. I have the following data:

```
date                 x  y  z
1990-01-01 13:00:00  1  NA NA
1990-01-01 14:00:00  NA 4  NA
1990-01-01 16:30:00  NA NA 3
1990-01-02 12:30:00  NA 2  NA
1990-01-02 13:30:00  NA NA 6
1990-01-02 14:30:00  2  NA NA
1990-01-03 09:30:00  NA 3  NA
1990-01-03 12:30:00  NA NA 4
1990-01-03 13:30:00  5  NA NA
...
```

What I need is to trim the data, such that I get the daily data and the NA's removed:

```
date        x  y  z
1990-01-01  1  4  3
1990-01-02  2  2  6
1990-01-03  5  3  4
```

I've kinda hit a blind spot on this one..

Comment: I don't have time to transcribe your sample data and test, so here's a thought: `x$date <- as.Date(x$date); library(dplyr); group_by(x,date) %>% summarize_at(vars(x,y,z), funs(na.omit(.)[1]))`. This is horrible, too, since it will not tell you when there are more than one non-`NA` in a day ... but perhaps it provides some inspiration.

Comment: What do you want to do when more than 1 `non-NA` value is present for a day? Max? Sum?

Comment: Since it is daily data, there shouldn't be more than 1 `non-NA`, but in that case, I guess Sum is preffered.
@r2evans: This works very well. However, is there any easier way to include multiple columns, in case of more columns than just 3 (x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this...

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(date=as.Date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize_all(~sum(.,na.rm=TRUE))

  date           x     y     z
  <date>     <int> <int> <int>
1 1990-01-01     1     4     3
2 1990-01-02     2     2     6
3 1990-01-03     5     3     4
```

Comment: I am getting and error: "Error in -date : invalid argument to unary operator".

Comment: @JeppeUdesen Sorry about that - see simpler edited solution above

Answer (score 0):

By using `summarise_all` from `dplyr`

```
df$date=as.Date(df$date)
df%>%group_by(date)%>%summarise_all(funs(sum(.,na.rm=T)))# more than one value not NA
#df%>%group_by(date)%>%summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1])), only remove NA
# A tibble: 3 x 4
        date     x     y     z
      <date> <int> <int> <int>
1 1990-01-01     1     4     3
2 1990-01-02     2     2     6
3 1990-01-03     5     3     4
```

Comment: This seems just to replace the NA's with zeros.